# How can I print multiple data from api to components one by one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Carts from './Carts/Carts'

export default function ApiRequest() {

    const [dataApi, setDataApi] = useState([])


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchApi = async () => {
            const request = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts")
            const data = await request.json()
            setDataApi(data.posts)

            console.log("gelen veri:", dataApi)
        }

        fetchApi()

    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Carts data={dataApi} />
        </>
    )
}
```

On this page, I provided the api connection and got the data. I sent this data to Carts page as props. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JjIK.png)

The incoming data is as you can see in the picture above.

I want to set the data here as the title and description on the Carts page one by one. Can you help me? What path should I follow.

```js
import React from 'react'

export default function Carts({title,description,data}) {


    console.log("gelen props:",data)

    

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="card-header">
                    <div className="cart-items">
                        <img src="" alt="" />
                        <div className="cart-head">
                            <h1>{title}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="cart-content">
                            <p>{description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Carts page!

Comment: Do you mean [map](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists)?

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense to reopen the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76963351/67579 since one can do this with a context processor, making it more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should map the cart component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Carts from './Carts/Carts'

export default function ApiRequest() {

    const [dataApi, setDataApi] = useState([])


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchApi = async () => {
            const request = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts")
            const data = await request.json()
            setDataApi(data.posts)

            console.log("gelen veri:", dataApi)
        }

        fetchApi()

    }, [])

    return (
        <>
{dataApi.map((data,id)=>(
<Carts data={data} key={id} />
)}     
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much worked 